# Algoritmo para identifique sons grave e agudo de músicas

Tags: algoritmo, áudio

Olá.
Gostaria de saber se alguém conseguiu fazer um código que identifique batidas de música.
Por exemplo um som de Grave de músicas eletrônicas.
Falo isso pois queria fazer um jogo que ele gera obstáculos no momento da batida do grave e alguns agudos .

O mais simples a se fazer seria isso aqui
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z2fNFmbAVCI

tun tun niiiiii
Para cada tun que tocar printaria A, para cada niii que tocar printaria B.

Alguém?
Falo isso porque vi dois jogos fazendo isso (Crypt of Necrodancer e o Scape Mellody) e gostaria de descorir como é feito isso e deixar esse código para o público usar.

Comment: olá, você precisa de ajuda em um código ou quer contratar alguém que programe pra você?

Comment: Conseguir essa ajuda ótimo.
Claro que gostaria deixasse essa solução aqui de forma pública para que pessoas além de mim possam reaproveitar-la.
Ou até reaproveitadas em engines.

Mas sim estou aberto a pagar por um profissional pra isso também.

Comment: Não entendi...
Porque estão negativando a minha pergunta?

Answer (score 1):

Você quer um `rhythm follow` ? precisa só descobrir quando as batidas acontecem e tomar uma ação ?

Não posso fazer por você, mas posso te dar um norte lol...

Estes algoritmos utilizam um combo de `filtros` para decompor o sinal de áudio em diferentes faixas de frequências, as batidas mais perceptíveis sempre vão estar nas faixas de frequências mais baixas, se você aplicar filtros nas faixas de frequências desejadas terá como retorno o envelope da amplitude contido no  áudio, o envelope das amplitudes vão sinalizar onde as batidas estão acontecendo...

Já faz muito tempo que escrevi uma breve explicação de como isso funciona [aqui](https://ederwander.wordpress.com/2012/10/21/audio-beat-track/), o meu código calcula quantas batidas por minuto uma música tem, para identificar isso é preciso encontrar as batidas contidas no áudio, você poderá utilizar isso em seu código e tomar uma ação ...

O meu código para calcular `bpm (beats per minute)` só vai resolver metade do problema, você também vai precisar identificar a frequência da batida (grave ou agudo), para isso você vai precisar desenvolver um `Pitch track`, desenvolvi um para o [tarsos](https://github.com/JorenSix/TarsosDSP) , meu código pode ser encontrado [aqui](https://github.com/JorenSix/TarsosDSP/blob/master/src/core/be/tarsos/dsp/pitch/AMDF.java), se as frequências das batidas já forem conhecidas, você poderá substituir o pitch track olhando apenas os resultados do envelope das amplitudes, claro neste caso você terá que ter dois filtros para decompor o áudio nas frequências esperadas, se encontrar picos maiores no envelope das frequências agudas tome ação para batidas agudas caso contrário tome ação para batida grave...

Existe uma maneira mais simples de identificar as batidas em tempo real, você pode calcular a diferença de decibéis do atual frame com o frame anterior, se os decibéis ultrapassarem um determinado limite proposto por você uma batida aconteceu, escrevi algo bem simples de como isso pode ser feito [aqui](https://ederwander.wordpress.com/2010/11/29/clap-detection/), claro esse método não é nada robusto.

Se a batida não for importante, quer apenas descobrir onde está os graves e os agudos? você vai precisar somente de um pitch track, detalhe importante o meu código para pitch track não vai funcionar bem em áudios polifônicos...

**EDIT**

Dei uma olhada no youtube em gameplays do `melody's escape`, é nítido o que o algoritmo faz, ele processa todo o áudio antes, analisa pedaço por pedaço, descobre quantas batidas por minuto o áudio contem, repara que quando as batidas por minuto  for alto o jogo fica mais rápido, ele também processa o pitch do áudio, isso é feito offline (antes de começar o game), depois de terminar a análise ele já vai saber quais são os locais do áudio onde as batidas são rápidas ou lentas, onde tem tonalidades graves e agudas, depois disso ele só precisa montar o level/obstáculos do game baseado nas análises, claro eu observei que ele também faz outras análises para deixar a sensação ritma do jogador mais real, ele por exemplo calcula se tem uma diferença abrupta de batidas, quando isso acontece sem a presença de `druns e kicks`  o algoritmo foca na extração do pitch(frequência), ele foca se alguma frequência possui sustentação e cria uma barra de deslise para a nota em questão....

Comment: Interessante, obrigado. Vou dar uma olhada no seu material e ver o que posso fazer